# How can I get the sum of a column ?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: activites, taks and requirements. I want to return all of the duration of all the tasks for a specific requirement. This is my query:

[image]

```
SELECT r.id as req_id, 
       r.project_id,
       r.name as req_name, 
       r.cost,r.estimated, 
       p.name as project_name, 
       v.name AS `status` , 
       t.taskid, 
       (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))) 
        FROM activities a   
        WHERE a.taskid = t.taskid) AS worked
FROM requirements r  
INNER JOIN projects p  
ON p.projectid = r.project_id
INNER JOIN `values` v 
ON v.id = r.r_status_id
LEFT JOIN tasks t
on t.id_requirement = r.id
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY req_id  desc
```

And this is the result : 
[image]

As you can see there are 2 same req_id (48) . I want to appear one time and get the sum of the last two rows in `worked`.  How can I manage that ?
this is the activities structure : 
[image]

this is tasks structure : 
[image]

and this is the requirement structure : 
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your title to make it more descriptive? meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your activities table in the JOIN, GROUP by all requirement columns you need and add a sum. Since you are aggregating tasks, you cannot have taskid in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT r.id as req_id, 
       r.project_id,
       r.name as req_name, 
       r.cost,r.estimated, 
       p.name as project_name, 
       v.name AS `status` , 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.duration))) 
FROM requirements r  
    INNER JOIN projects p ON p.projectid = r.project_id
    INNER JOIN `values` v ON v.id = r.r_status_id
    LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.id_requirement = r.id
    LEFT JOIN activities a ON a.taskid=t.taskid
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY r.id, r.project_id, r.name,r.cost,r.estimated,p.name, v.name
ORDER BY req_id  desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The joins in your query appear to be creating extra rows.  I'm sure there is a way to fix the logic directly, possibly by pre-aggregating some results in the `from` clause.

Your duplicates appear to be complete duplicates (every column is exactly the same).  The easy way to fix the problem is to use `select distinct`.  So, just start your query with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id as req_id, r.project_id, r.name as req_name, 
. . .
```

I suspect that one of your underlying tables has duplicated rows that you are not expecting, but that is another issue.

Comment: I tried with distinct, but I the same result, I get the duplicates

Comment: @Chester . . . Now that I look closer, those are for two different tasks.  The query is doing what you want, because you are listing the tasks.